# UIINavigationController in UITabBarController: How to go to root view on tab selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar

I have a UITabBarController with four views and each one of them have a UINavigationController.

Some of those views have segue to other subviews, but if I am in a subview and then select other tabbar item and again the previous tabbar item, the navigation controller isn't on its root view.

To fix this problem I have the following code, which I found in other similar questions:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

But in this case if I select other tabbar item and again the previous one, the app crashes without any error message.

Could somebody help me with this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: Just use below this line:-

 [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

and after this push into view which you want to navigate.

Answer (score -1):

When the crash occurs, do you have the exception breakpoint set ? It will tell you most of the time on which line the crash has occurred.

To set the exception breakpoint, look in the left pane in Xcode and select the Breakpoint navigator view. Than, at the bottom of the screen, press the + and select it.

Run the app again.